# Reference request for Kato's paper: A generalization of local class field theory by using K -groups

Tags: nt.number-theory, reference-request, local-fields, paper-request

I would like to ask for the paper of Kato: A generalization of local class field theory by using K -groups I, J. Fac. Sci. Univ. Tokyo Sec. IA 26 No.2, 1979, 303–376. I could not find it. Could anyone help?

Thanks.

Comment: here it is: https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.pja/1195518054

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but it is a short version. The version I asked is much longer.

Comment: This is not Kato's paper, but on higher local class field theory using Milnor $K$-theory: https://msp.org/gtm/2000/03/gtm-2000-03p.pdf Perhaps this helps you.

Comment: If you're still looking, I could help.

Answer (score 8):

I found this old question while searching for Kato's paper myself. Just in case anyone else is also still looking for these, here's what I found.

Kato's work was published in three installments in J. Fac. Sci. Univ. Tokyo. The old issues of this journal have now been posted online, with DOI's, so you can get the full versions here:

- K. Kato, *A generalization of local class field theory by using K -groups I* (76 pages):
  [DOI: 10.15083/00077072](http://doi.org/10.15083/00077072)
- K. Kato, *A generalization of local class field theory by using K -groups II* (80 pages): [DOI: 10.15083/00077073](http://doi.org/10.15083/00077073)
- K. Kato, *A generalization of local class field theory by using K -groups III* (12 pages): [DOI: 10.15083/00077074](http://doi.org/10.15083/00077074)

Answer (score 4):

Here are all three parts of the paper (till January 26): https://we.tl/t-TQqTkYjRZK

Comment: I don't know if the OP ever saw this.  I will reup if I hear from the OP.

Comment: Could you please reupload the files? Thanks.

Comment: Here you are Huy Quoc Dang: https://we.tl/t-TnaRwKmfqi